# Integration of protobuf-dt with protoc not working

Tags: eclipse, protocol-buffers

I've installed the Protobuf-dt plugin in Eclipse and It's working okay, except for a weird problem related to it's integration with Protoc.

When I point it to it's executable, it says the file isn't protoc. If I point it to PATH, it doesn't show me any error but when I save the .proto file, it shows me an error saying that it haven't found protoc.

[image: Eclipse - Preferences - Protocol Buffer - Compiler]

If I compile my .proto file manually with command line (using the same executable), it works okay.

Could it be a problem related to my 64 bits environment (windows/eclipse/jdk)? I haven't found a win64 executable of protoc.

Does anyone had the same problem? Any tip would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was some Bug. I raised an Issue on theirs Google Code page and they seem to have fixed.

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-dt/issues/detail?id=103